# Sharepoint 365 and SQL Access

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I am new to SharePoint Online in Office 365 and I am trying to create an `asp` page that gets data from certain lists using `CAML` queries.

But was wondering if there is a way that I can do this using SQL? (by connecting directly the SharePoint to SQL server)

And if you can give me some pointers or guide on how to connect and create reports from SharePoint lists that would be great as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your end goal is to generate reports over SharePoint Online(that's the SharePoint version available with O365), there are couple of different options that you can try:

**1. Power BI:**

For a small fees, power bi capabilities are available as an app inside O365. Power BI can get data from vast number of sources which includes SP lists, and it has beautiful interactive chart controls. Power Bi also has Natural Language Query which helps you write ad-hoc queries against the data model in Power BI. To understand the power bi power, I'd recommend watching Amir Netz demonstration of Power BI.

Note that there is a free version of Power BI online which may suffice your needs and you can directly query SP list and creates dashboards and charts in Power BI.

**2. Use OData feed**

SP list data can be exposed as OData feeds which can be directly consumed by your application or can be modulated using SSIS before consumption.

Incidentally this how MS exposes List data to excel and Power BI.

**3. Consume SP lists inside Excel**

If ends matter more than means, and you can satisfy your client with excel reports which sync in real time, you can save yourself from building a web app and leverage all excel charting controls as well as Power BI in excel too. SP lists can be directly accessed in Excel Power BI and you can create Pivots and charts and what not over them.

**4. Use SP apps**

You can use  0365 apps to access SP content and create charts/reports over it.

**5. Bring data to SQL**
There are many ways to bring data to SQL. A quick google search gave me this good [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-ways-export-sharepoint-data-sql-server-paul-gallagher). I would prefer SP --> SSIS --> SQL approach.

**6. Direct store to SQL**
There's a thing called ***external content type (ECT)*** which can be used in ***external lists***.

External lists are mostly like lists, but have certain restrictions. See this [office documentation link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-native-and-external-lists-6601eda9-b722-4bf8-a2bf-ce25cf3d2fd0) for difference in features.

External content types encapsulate the SQL server database tables and act as BCS containers for them.

*So using ECT in external list on SP, you can directly update SQL server tables with SharePoint forms.*

The tool which will help you achieve this is SharePoint Designer. There many good video tutorials and a lot of documentation on web which will help you with this.

**Caveat:** SharePoint Online in O365 only supports Azure SQL database officially.

**Hack:** But I have been successful in creating CRUD forms in SharePoint Online over On-premise SQL server installation. While doing this I discovered this is possible iff:

- SQL instance is the default instance
- SQL server is running on default ports

Using this approach allows you to directly pull data into application from SQL server.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I heard about BI from the other forums as well and will try it out. :)